# Set Java / Tomcat heap size (Xmx) without modifying catalina.sh

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, heap-memory

Most people seem to suggest setting the Java/Tomcat heap memory size for Tomcat6 by editing the /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh file, and adding something like:

```
# Set specific memory requirements for Tomcat6 (for server with ~512MB RAM).
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xms128m -Xmx256m"
```

I am trying to build an Ansible playbook to configure a Tomcat-based server on Ubuntu, and it doesn't seem to me like having an entire custom catalina.sh file would be ideal—is there some other configuration file or local settings file/system used by Tomcat and/or Java to get the `Xms` and `Xmx` values?

Or... do most people use a custom catalina.sh file, and I'm just making a mountain out of a molehill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are launching via the "catalina.sh" script (directly or indirectly), then you have two options:

- Modify ("hack"!) the script as suggested.
- Find where the script is being invoked, and ensuring that `CATALINA_OPTS` is set to include the "-mx" option ... and exported ...

The latter is probably "cleaner", but there is no simple, one-size-fits-all way to get that variable set and exported.  If you are launching Tomcat as a service, it depends on how your distro has wrapped Tomcat.

> [Am I] just making a mountain out of a molehill?

It depends.  If you are just doing this on a non-production platform, then Yes.  If you are trying to build a production system that will continue to work over package upgrades and upgrades in your distro version, then No.  (In the latter case, it is worth figuring out the best way to do this *for your particular distro*.)

Comment: Thanks! I am working on building a production platform—where one configuration will be deployed to tens (hopefully someday, hundreds or more) of prod servers, so I'd like to do it *right*. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Tomcat6 and Solr 3.6.x, FYI.

Comment: In that case, there should be a shell script in "/etc/init.d/" called "tomcat" or "tomcat6".  Look at the script to see how it handles CATALINA_OPTS.  Some versions source a "defaults" script from somewhere ... and that's where you would put your "-xmx" setting.

Comment: What I ended up doing is adding the following to `/etc/environment`: `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms256m -Xmx256m"`

Answer (score 6):

Tomcat reads `setenv.sh` from bin directory for these extra settings. `setenv.sh` doesn't come with tomcat but you can create one for you and set CATALINA_OPTS in that.

Using JAVA_OPTS to set memory is not suggested by [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) because it applies to both startup and shutdown.

Comment: This is a much better way

Answer (score 0):

For clarity: I used this in a setenv.sh script that goes in tomcat/bin. I can verify that it works for Ansible or my own install scripts:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xms512m -Xmx2048m"
```

Note that this worked for Tomcat 8 but should work for Tomcat 7 too.